# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

Tags: java, junit

So my problem is in a Test, when I call the method to test it gives this error:

> ```
> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
>   at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:143)
>   at com.MD.Medicine.Services.SaveService.savePlans(SaveService.java:57)
>   at com.MD.Medicine.Services.SaveServiceTest.testSavePlans_failPills(SaveServiceTest.java:99)
>   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
>   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> ```

My test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SaveServiceTest {

@MockBean
private MedsRepo medsRepo;
@MockBean
private PlansRepo plansRepo;
@MockBean
private PlanDayRepo planDayRepo;
@Autowired
private SaveService saveService;
 @Test
void testSavePlans_failPills() {

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    Date date3 = new Date(1673740800000L);
    Set<PlanDay> setPlans = new HashSet<>();
    Plans plans = new Plans(1, setPlans);
    BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(8.00);
    Meds meds = new Meds(1, "Brufen", price, "Pain", 200, date, setPlans);
    when(medsRepo.getReferenceById(meds.getMedsId())).thenReturn(meds);
    int pillNumber = meds.getPillNumber();
 
    List<PlanDay> planList3 = new ArrayList<PlanDay>();
    
  
    PlanDay planDay3 = new PlanDay(1, date3, "Tuesday", plans, meds, 50000);

    planList3.add(planDay3);


    String expected3 = saveService.savePlans(planList3);
    assertThat(expected3).isEqualTo("Error: No piils available (Existing Pills: " + pillNumber + ")");

}
```

When it gets in * String expected3 = saveService.savePlans(planList3);* it stops and prints the error.

The method:

```
    public String savePlans(List<PlanDay> plans) throws Error {

    //long planIdVerify = plans.get(0).getPlanDaysId();
    Date firstDate = plans.get(0).getPlanDate();
    long todayMili = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long dateLimitMili = firstDate.getTime() + 604800000;

    long planId = plans.get(0).getPlans().getPlanId();
    Plans plansWithId = new Plans();
    plansWithId.setPlanId(planId);
    plansRepo.save(plansWithId);

    for (int i = 0; i < plans.size(); i++) {
        long planDateInMili = plans.get(i).getPlanDate().getTime();
        //long planIdMultiVerify = plans.get(i).getPlanDaysId();
        if (planDateInMili <= dateLimitMili && todayMili<planDateInMili ) {

            PlanDay planDay = plans.get(i);
            long medsId = planDay.getMeds().getMedsId();
            int medsToTake = planDay.getMedsToTake();
            int pillNumber = medsRepo.getReferenceById(medsId).getPillNumber();
            int pillUpdate = pillNumber - medsToTake;
            Meds updatePlanDay = medsRepo.findById(medsId).get();
                if (pillUpdate > 0) {
                    updatePlanDay.setPillNumber(pillUpdate);
                } else {
                    return "Error: No piils available (Existing Pills: " + pillNumber + ")";
                }
            planDayRepo.save(planDay);
        } else {
            return "Week time interval not correct/Invalid planId (only one plan can be saved)";
        }

    }

    return "Saved Successfully";
}
```

and my entities:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "meds")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "days" })
public class Meds {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long medsId;

@Column
private String medsName;

@Column
private BigDecimal price;

@Column
private String category;

@Column
private int pillNumber;

@Column
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDate medsDate;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "meds", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Set<PlanDay> days = new HashSet<PlanDay>();
```

}

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "planDay")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "planDaysId" })
public class PlanDay {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long planDaysId;

@Column
private Date planDate;

@Column
private String weekday;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "planId", nullable = false)
private Plans plans;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "medsId", nullable = false)
private Meds meds;

@Column
private int medsToTake;
```

}

I have been looking for a solution and the `orElse()` method was one of the options but I can't make it work.. What would be a solution for this problem?
Kind Regards.

Comment: `Meds updatePlanDay = medsRepo.findById(medsId).get();` what happens if there's no record with that id? An immediate solution might be to mock the repository, but are you sure that in the grand scheme of thing you'll always have a record with that id?

Comment: No it might just be null, I may have nothing in the DB

Comment: Then you'll have to decide what happens in that case, because `medsRepo.findById(medsId)` will return an empty `Optional` that will go boom (as you can see) when no record is found. The answer to this question pretty much depends on what you want to do in that case.

Comment: Could I fix that with the orElse(null) method?

Comment: Sure, just do `medsRepo,findById(medsId).orElse(null)`, but that will throw a `NullPointerException` just two rows after (inside the `if`, when `pillUpdate > 0`). Again, you should rethink what you want to do when that returns an empty `Optional` and then adapt your code to the circumstances, don't just skirt around `Optional`.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much! And sorry to bother but what could be a better solution? Just to point me in the correct direction regarding what the code should do when the medsRepo,findById(medsId) is empty

Comment: There's no general purpose solution. In your case I'm not even sure what you expect to happen when everything goes according to plan, since you never save `updatePlanDay` after you modify it, so it's really hard to help you devise a solution for when things go wrong. But if you just need a general introduction on how to use (and, especially, how *not* to use) `Optional` [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/optional-in-java) should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MedsRepo is a MockBean when you call `medsRepo.findById(medsId)` it will return an empty optional because you have no `when` for that method.

```java
int pillNumber = medsRepo.getReferenceById(medsId).getPillNumber(); //extract the Meds as a variable and keep using this
int pillUpdate = pillNumber - medsToTake;
Meds updatePlanDay = medsRepo.findById(medsId).get(); //trying to get the same as you did above
```

Should be

```java
Meds updatePlanDay = medsRepo.getReferenceById(medsId);
int pillNumber = updatePlanDay.getPillNumber(); 
int pillUpdate = pillNumber - medsToTake;
//Meds updatePlanDay = medsRepo.findById(medsId).get(); no longer needed
```

Also on a different note you should look into the difference between `findById` and `getReferenceById` and what happens when there is no `Meds` with that `medsId`